# Determine which of the following exist?

Tags: integration

$\int_6^\infty $$\frac {1}{xlogx} dx$

$\int_6^\infty $$\frac {1}{x(logx)^2} dx$

$\int_2^\infty $$\frac {1}{x^2+20x+1} dx$

$\int_1^\infty $$(\frac {sinx}{x})^2 dx$

What is a general way to determine the existence of integrals like these?

Can anyone show me how to deal with any one the above integrals so that I can have an intuitive idea as to how to solve these problems?

Comment: What tests do you know? There are several that are absolutely standard in any calculus course.

Answer (score 1):

We will give either upper estimate or exact answer to each question. Start with:

$1)$ $$\displaystyle \int_{6}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x\log x}dx = \log(\log x)|_{x=6}^{\infty} = +\infty$$

$2)$ $$\displaystyle \int_{6}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x(\log x)^2}dx= \left(-\dfrac{1}{\log x}\right)|_{x=6}^{\infty}= \dfrac{1}{\log 6}$$

$3)$ $$0 <\displaystyle \int_{2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2+20x+1}dx< \displaystyle \int_{2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2}dx = \left(-\dfrac{1}
{x}\right)|_{x=2}^{\infty}= \dfrac{1}{2}$$

$4)$ $$0 <\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2dx < \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2dx= \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$.

From the above computation and comparison, you can see which integrals converges or diverges.

Note: For $4)$, I have not looked up the analysis book to confirm the exact answer,but I think it is finite and related to $\pi$.